# Send req.file to another EndPoint using multer result is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, axios, multer

I'm trying to send the filesI received using multer to another endpoint but on the other endpoint I get **undefined** **req.file**

**- Here I have created a form and added the data I received to it, then I'm sending it to the other endpoint using axios**

```
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('file', Readable.from(req.files[i].buffer)),{
      filename: req.files[i].originalname,
    }
    body.append('mimetype' , req.files[i].mimetype);


    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/image/images/create", body, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    })
```

**- Here I'm using multer in the other endpoint, however in the controller the file I get is undefined, I only receive the body of the request**

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

imageRouter.post('/images/create', upload.single("file"), imageController.postImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not including `headers`, and also try appending file buffer without converting it to stream. Also, `mimetype` can be included in the file information object.

Try this:

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('file', req.files[i].buffer, {
  filename: req.files[i].originalname,
  contentType: req.files[i].mimetype
})


const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/image/images/create", body);
```

Comment: I've tried it, but I'm still getting the same problem req.files is undefined

Comment: are you logging `req.files` or `req.file`. it should be in `req.file`. also, try logging `req.files[i].buffer`, to make sure it's a buffer

Comment: can you include the code where you process `req.files` and maybe how you pass them to that method

Comment: image-controller code: 
`
const postImage = async (
  req: ExpRequest,
  res: ExpResponse,
  next: ExpNextFunc
) => {
    console.log("here")
    console.log(req.body);

    console.log(req.files[0])
`

image-router code:
`
const imageRouter = Router();


const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

imageRouter.post('/images/create', upload.single("file"), imageController.postImage);
`

Comment: just use edit feature. it's not clear what sends what.. it seems you're mixing `req.files` and `req.file`..

Comment: I have tried req.files[i].buffer, but it throws an error saying that we can't access an undefined array member

Comment: I apologize, I have forgot to modify, it's supposed to be: console.log(req.file), that's it. still undefined

Comment: you should include the code where you log that, otherwise it's impossible to say.. also, include the code where you get `req.files`, it would seem something is wrong there

Comment: There's an update, I'm getting "req.file" in the image-controller, but when I log it, I can't see the value of buffer and I don't know how to access it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/KarimAboshamia/40deec98cedf4a67df8bd5f654d78ca3
this gist includes all the code involved in this process

Comment: _I'm getting "req.file" in the image-controller, but when I log it, I can't see the value of buffer and I don't know how to access it_ -  this means that file upload is working, and that your problem is solved. `buffer` property is available only when using `memoryStorage`, and you're saving it locally in `imageRouter`. if you want that property, change upload middleware to use `memoryStorage` as you have in `productRouter`

Comment: and also you need to change `req.body.buffer` to `req.file.buffer`, and `req.body.mimetype` to `req.file.mimetype`